# Slack UI crashing on start - Ubuntu 20.04.02

Tags: 20.04, crash, slack

As I wrote, Slack Desktop UI keeps crashing on start-up. This is a deb package downloaded from the Slack official website (not Snap). The version installed is 4.14, the system is at 20.04.2 (latest update) vanilla.

The notification shows top right and opens the menu, however when I try to bring the UI up, nothing happens.

I started slack from the command line, to see if I can catch some output and it does seem to show a crash report:

```
slack
Initializing local storage instance
(electron) Sending uncompressed crash reports is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Electron. Set { compress: true } to opt-in to the new behavior. Crash reports will be uploaded gzipped, which most crash reporting servers support.
(node:172444) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
(Use `slack --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
(electron) 'BrowserWindow.getDevToolsExtensions' is deprecated and will be removed. Please use 'session.getAllExtensions' instead.
[04/16/21, 15:14:50:866] info: 
╔═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║      Slack 4.14.0, linux 5.4.0-70-generic on x64      ║
╚═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝ 
[04/16/21, 15:14:50:867] info: Configured logger via 
{
  "enableConsoleTransport": true,
  "identifierOverride": "webapp-service-worker-console",
  "shouldUseNewBackend": false,
  "loggerInstanceCount": 2
}
[04/16/21, 15:14:50:868] info: Predefined values for process 
{
  "NODE_ENV": "production",
  "platform": "linux",
  "type": "browser",
  "timeZone": "Europe/London",
  "PACKAGE_MANIFEST.productName": "Slack",
  "PACKAGE_MANIFEST.version": "4.14.0",
  "PACKAGE_MANIFEST.commit": "252046e",
  "PACKAGE_MANIFEST.branch": "HEAD"
}

Unexpected crash report id length
Failed to get crash dump id.
Report Id:
```

Any ideas / Suggestions?

Comment: You wont like it I would start by removing that program.

Comment: "and it does seem to show a crash report" it does indeed but all of these are -warnings- ... what is more interesting is what the crash is (ie the error) and that this does not show ;-)

Comment: @David - thanks I thought to reduce my question - but the initial install was a Snap which I purged, then a .deb which I purged a few times and re-installed. All other questions on here seem to show that removing the Snap and installing the .deb solves the issue, with me it does not.

Comment: @Rinzwind - thanks for that: any ideas **where I can get that information (error)**? Quite frankly, yep - if I'd see what the error is, I would potentially be able to find the solution :-)